# Prepositions at the end of arbitrary sentences

Tags: grammar

I know about the possibility to reorder words in special questions so that sentences like "For whom...?" become "Who... for?".

Wonder can this rule be extended to the other sentences? Could one say in English like:

"The first date of the period to delete events from". // I expect it to describe a form field on a website.

Comment: The example you give as an "arbitrary sentence" wouldn't come from a sentence at all, "From the first date of the period to delete events" is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: In addition questions typically have some kind of inversion already (**the bell tolls for *you*** ==> Who does the bell toll for? OR For who does the bell toll?). The "reordering" you reference is really just deciding what the subject of your sentence is "who" or "for whom".

Comment: *"The earliest date from which to delete events"* is a possiblity, but I would probably label the field differently--perhaps *"Delete events that start after: [--/--/--]"* or *"Delete events that start before: [--/--/--]"*.  [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) might have a better opinion...